# getting error while freezing first few layers in vgg19

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential,Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import 
Dense,Dropout,Flatten,BatchNormalization,Conv2D,MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19,preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

#defining the image size
num_classes=7
img_width=224
img_height=224
batch_size_training=32
batch_size_validation=32
data_generator=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_inpu)
```

Fetching the image from directory:

```
train_generator=data_generator.flow_from_directory
   ('C:/Users/pauls/Desktop/Python Rev1/Dataset/Train/',target_size= 
   (224,224),batch_size=20,class_mode='categorical')
test_generator=data_generator.flow_from_directory
   ('C:/Users/pauls/Desktop/Python Rev1/Dataset/Test/',target_size= 
   (224,224),batch_size=20,class_mode='categorical')
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Please add the error message. and specify which line raise this error.

Comment: ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_2/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_2/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,256], [3,3,256,512].

Comment: Somewhere in your model definition, the input size shrinks to 1, and then conv2d layer or maxpool layer can not operate on this size. Check the input size and it's change through each layer.